# How can you get the group header value in an Excel Pivot Table from any cell in the pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a standard pivot table in Excel of which I have several rows and columns of data being displayed. For the sake of this discussion, the names of the Rows (in order) for the pivot table are Resource, Project. For the Columns, I have Time.

What I am trying to do is find a function or programmatic way to find the header row under which a Project or Time cell live. Here's a table visual of what I'm trying to achieve:

| **Paul** |  |
| --- | --- |
| ACME | 20 |
| Walmart | 40 |
| **Dave** |  |
| ---------- | -------- |
| Target | 30 |
| Amazon | 50 |

So, in my example, if I click on the cell with 40 in it, I'd like to use a function or code to be able to get back "Paul", if I click on 50, I'd like to get back "Dave". Is this possible?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me, appreciate it!

I've tried to use the GETPIVOTDATA function, but I can't seem to be able to grab that data.